# I have a structure variables with similar names, how to print them out in c

Tags: c, loops, structure

I have similar struct variables. How to print their data using loops.

```
struct employee{
int cardNo;
char name[20];
char surname[20];
long salary;
int age;
};
struct employee emp1={1,"abc","xyz",70,000,30}; //I have similar variables named emp2, emp3.....till emp20

int main()
{
   //i need to print the salary of all 20 employees using a loop. How to do it?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using 20 separate variables. Use an array instead.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having a separate variable for each employee, make an array of them:

```
struct employee emps[] = {
    {1,"abc","xyz",70,000,30},
    {2,"def","zzz",60,400,20},
    ...
}
```

And loop through them.

Comment: Can you please show how to print salary for each employee i.e how to iterate

Comment: Warning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62489457/how-to-initialize-similar-variables-using-while-loop

Answer (score 1):

You can define an array of structures so that you can do this in the loop. However, it may be easier to write a print function instead of doing this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct employee
{
    int cardNo;
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    long salary;
    int age;
}Employee;

void print_employee_information(const struct employee *p)
{
    printf("%d %s %s %ld %d\n", p->cardNo, p->name, p->surname, p->salary, p->age);
}

int main()
{
    
    struct employee emps[] = {
        {1, "abc", "xyz", 70, 000},
        {2, "def", "zzz", 60, 400},
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        Employee *p = (emps+i);
        print_employee_information(p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass `emps + i` instead of creating a new pointer? Also why did you define type `Employee` and didn't use it?

Comment: @WENDYN Yes, I agree with you. There are these issues as I get some of the code from the comment at the top and from the subject owner's code.

Answer (score 0):

Store them in array, like this:

```
struct employee emps[] = {
    { 1, "abc", "def", 20, 000 },
    { 2, "ghi", "jkl", 20, 001 },
    ...
};
```

or like this

```
struct employee emps[] = {
    emp1,
    emp2,
    ...
};
```

and then you can go through them like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < empLastIndex; i++)
{
    ...
    emps[i]
    ...
}
```